# routes are not defined when calling calcRoute with params (latLng) - Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, map-directions

I need to call pass params to `calcRoute()` on click, what I am doing is:

```
function calcRoute(source,destt) {
  var start = new google.maps.LatLng(source);
  var end = new google.maps.LatLng(destt);
  var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    } 
  });
}
```

Click Event:

```
$('#go').click(function(){
  var from= "24.942834,67.121237";
  var to = "24.944908,67.124491";
  calcRoute(from,to);
});
```

It's returning the status with `ZERO_RESULT`

It was working fine when I hard coded lat n lng in calcRoute(), i.e

```
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(24.942834,67.121237);
var end = new google.maps.LatLng(24.944908,67.124491);
```

Thanks for any Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct string will not work as `LatLng` object you have to convert  `"24.942834,67.121237"`  to  `google.maps.LatLng` to make it work.

```
$('#go').click(function(){
          var from= new google.maps.LatLng(24.942834,67.121237);// convert it to latlng object
          var to = new google.maps.LatLng(24.944908,67.124491);
          calcRoute(from,to);
        });
```

if you have `"24.942834,67.121237"` then you can use it like this:

```
var str="24.942834,67.121237";
var latlng=str.split(',')

var to = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlng[0]), parseFloat(latlng[1]));
```

Comment: Hmmm, lemme implement.